# How to set the scroll position in ui::ScrollView programmatically?

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

Say I have a scrollview whose contentSize is the size of the visible screen

Eg:

```
Content Size = 320 x 480
InnerContainer = 900 x 480
```

How can I set the scroll position programmatically ? For example, if there is an object at (400,100), how would I programmatically scroll the view so that the object is visible ?

There seems to be methods for setting the scroll bar position, but I don't think that actually scrolls the view.

I am using cocos2d-x v3.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use: [`setInnerContainerPosition()`](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/reference/native-cpp/V3.9/d8/d29/classcocos2d_1_1ui_1_1_scroll_view.html#aabdd70c0f481d59dbbd3a30c6cbe3ac4)